# Issue during running in cmdprmpt

Tags: environment-variables, compiler-construction, conan

`conan install . --build=missing --update -o cura:devtools=True -g VirtualPythonEnv`

Getting error during I run these cmd lines

ERROR: compiler not defined for compiler.cppstd
Please define compiler value first too

Even I changed the settings in profile by adding few cmpl details but still facing issues

Comment: The ``compiler`` settings were not defined. It is possible that there is no C++ compiler installed in your system, or Conan was not able to detect it.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to share the settings in your profile?